# Python subtract list of strings from another list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

I would like to subtract a list of strings where there are more than one element of the same (so set operations are not useful).

Example:

```
C = ['A','B','B']
D = ['B']
```

I would like a way to do so that:

```
C - D = ['A','B']
```

Example of what I got so far, but does not give the result I want

```
[item for item in C if item not in D]
returns: ['A']
```

**Here is a more elaborated example to show what I want:**

```
C = ['A','B', 'A','A','B','B','B','X','B']

D = ['A','B','B','Y']
```

This is what I want the result to be:

```
C - D = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B','B','X']
```

Answer (score 6):

Without using any libraries:

```
output = [x for x in C if not x in D or D.remove(x)]

//output: ['A', 'B']
```

Comment: Clever use of the None return from remove() +1

Comment: This way seem to change the result somehow -- If I run it more than once it's adding an extra B to the result. Not sure what happens, but something is not doing as I would expect or want.

Answer (score 5):

Though Alain T.'s way is okay, there is a better way using `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
C = ['A','B','B']
D = ['B']
result = list((Counter(C) - Counter(D)).elements())
```

Comment: @jslatane There is a difference, although it doesn't show in this example because the count for every element is one. To show the difference, `list(Counter(a=1, b=2)) == ['a', 'b']` while `list(Counter(a=1, b=2).elements()) == ['a', 'b', 'b']`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Counter from collections:

```
from collections import Counter
C_D = [i for v,c in (Counter(C)-Counter(D)).items() for i in v*c]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
C = ['A','B', 'A','A','B','B','B','X','B']
D = ['A','B','B','Y']

res = [ i for i in C ]

for i in D:
  if i in C:
    res.remove(i)

print(res)
```

Comment: This will raise an error for something like `C = ['B']` and `D = ['B', 'B']`